# How do I add name to alert after successful validation in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a local App with hardcoded users for login(test purposes), I want to be able to alert a welcome + name of the user after successful validation. Hers's what I've done below

```
const Users = [
    {
      email: "test@admin.com",
      password: "admin",
      name:"Admin"
    },
    {
      email: "mine@yahoo.com",
      password: "user123",
      name:"Admin2"
    },
]

function App() {
 

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const login = (details) => {
    const isUserValid = Users.some((user) => {
      const email = details.email;
      const password = details.password;
      return user.email === email && user.password === password;
    });

   
    if (isUserValid) {
      toast.success( `Welcome ${Users.name}`)
      navigate("/");
    } else {
      toast.error("‍♂️ Invalid email or password! Please check your entries.",);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <ToastContainer />
     
        //other stuff
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I get welcome undefine, please what am I missing I would appreciate any help. NB i'm using react-toastify for alert

Comment: `Users` is an array of objects. `Users.name` does not exist, hence `undefined`. You want `details.name` probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
toast.success( `Welcome ${Users.name}`)
```

In this line, you are fetching the name from the Users array declared at the top. You have not stored the valid logged in user anywhere.

To get that, you can use filter.

```
const validUser = Users.find((user) => {
  const email = details.email;
  const password = details.password;
  return user.email === email && user.password === password;
});


if (validUser) {
  toast.success( `Welcome ${validUser.name}`)
  navigate("/");
} else {
  toast.error("‍♂️ Invalid email or password! Please check your entries.",);
}
```